# electron <webview> isnt getting fullscreen?

Tags: html, node.js, electron, desktop-application

im working at the moment on a desktp client for a project im workin as webdeveloper / sysadmin. So my great idea was to build the desktp client simple as easy using electron :D
but it isnt working :c
i used the  but the result is pretty uncool ... https://i.gyazo.com/fc71a28e608da9aaf272ef1de08cdeb3.png [image link using gyazo]

the sourcecode is aviable @ [https://github.com/MineasiaMC/Desktop-Clients]

Answer (score 0):

Use css.

Something like:

```
webview {
     display: flex;  
     width: 100%;
     height: 98%;
     border: none;
}
```